# Rails newbie: How to add routes to a rails 3 engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to write my first rails 3 gem - everything works well, except for routes - I can't seem to get them working. It's possible this is a very simple error - as mentioned, it's my first experience with engines. The gem itself is very, very basic - literally just one scaffold

My gem's config/routes file:

```
class ActionController::Routing::RouteSet
  resources :frogs
end
```

...And when I try to start the server, I get the following error:

> /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/cancandevise-0.1.0/config/routes.rb:3:in
>   `<class:RouteSet>': undefined method`
>   resources' for
>   ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:Class
>   (NoMethodError)

Any suggestions much appreciated. At the present moment, the gem is nothing more than a very basic rails-generated 'frog' scaffold

Cheers,
          - JB

Comment: Is this a typo `resources: frogs`; as it should be `resources :frogs`? Might be the cause of your problem...

Comment: Thankfully it was correct in the file. Cheers anyway...that woulda been embarrassing. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@marcgg, I believe that's the syntax for a regular rails app, but I think he's talking about an engine.

@unclaimedbaggage, your engine/gem routes file should look like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do |map|
  resources :frogs
end
```

I made an example engine that touches on all the common setup issues I encountered when creating my first gem, you might find it helpful to reference:

http://keithschacht.com/creating-a-rails-3-engine-plugin-gem/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I get why you're using a routeset. What file did you show? Did you try this:

```
   YourApp::Application.routes.draw do |map|  
     resources :frogs
   end
```

More info here: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/203-routing-in-rails-3

Comment: I couldn't do this because, being part of a gem, 'YourApp' could have any value. However you're kinda right - I shoulda been drawing. I got it working with Rails.application.routes.draw do |map| ...Thanks. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add an alternative here, as I'm not sure @Keith Schact is doing it the [conventional](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#routes) way, this worked for me:

```
MyEngine::Engine.routes.draw do
  resources :frogs
end
```

then in the application that requires the gem:

`mount MyEngine::Engine => '/my_engine', :as => :some_namespace`

The url you will get is then:

`http://myserver.com/some_namespace/frogs`